# What's wrong with my survival object?

Tags: r, na, quantile, survival-analysis

I have a survival object in `R`.

`print(surv)` gives me

```
> print(surv)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(TAGE, EVENT) ~ 1, data = data_LTC[data_LTC$TYPE == 
    "Job", ])

records   n.max n.start  events  median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL 
 299510  299510  299510  252884     177     173     180
```

However, `quantile(surv)` does not work and outputs

```
> quantile(surv)
Error in is.na(y) : 'y' is missing
```

For me that's somehow weird, because `R` is able to calculate a median (177) but not the other quartiles.

What's wrong with my survival object?

[edit]
maybe this is a minimum example of the problem:
In the documentation (http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/survival/html/quantile.survfit.html) there's this example:

```
> fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data=lung)
> quantile(fit)
$quantile
          25% 50% 75%
ph.ecog=0 285 394 655
ph.ecog=1 181 306 550
ph.ecog=2 105 199 351
ph.ecog=3 118 118 118
...
```

Now, if I would like to repeat just the first line of this output, I would do

```
> fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung[lung$ph.ecog == 0,])
> quantile(fit)
Error in is.na(y) : 'y' is missing
```

@Edwin suggested below to use `quantile(fit$time)` instead

```
> quantile(fit$time)
     0%     25%     50%     75%    100% 
   5.00  224.25  301.50  439.75 1010.00
```

which however leads to different results, obviously.

**[Closed]**
Please ignore the answers below as they don't make use of `quantile.survfit` in the `survival` package, but use `R`s built-in `quantile`-function.

Update to the latest version of the `survival`-package to solve this issue.

Do this with

```
update.packages()
```

Note that you may need root privileges to do so.

Comment: maybe you can set `options(error=recover)` to see debug y values..

Comment: Also, describe how you obtained the surv object.

Comment: What do you expect the surv object to be, exactly? What are you trying to do?

Comment: There *is* a `survfit` method for the `quantile` function, so without a fully reproducible example, it will be difficult to determine what's going wrong. Perhaps also make sure that you have the latest version of the `survival` package. But *please* include a reproducible example. Ah, nice example. Hadn't refreshed before posting comment!

Comment: @BenBarnes is the example I just added alright?

Comment: Nice example. However, it works for me. Are you using the latest version of the `survival` package? (I'm using 2.37-4) Or do things work when you use `survival:::quantile.survfit(fit)`?

Comment: ok, maybe it's because my version of survival is 2.36-14 I'll upgrade it and report in a minute!

Comment: seems like the outdated version of the survival package was the reason. Another working day lost because of outdated software ;-) would you like to write a short answer so that I can accept your hint? Thank you, by the way!

Comment: @speendo, since this problem likely affects only a very (and increasingly) small group of people, I would actually encourage you to close the question. I'm glad to have helped, though!

Comment: ok! thank you again - especially for pointing out that there's a `survfit` method for `quantile`. I was aware of that, however, I was willing to believe that `quantile(surv.object$time)` makes use of it aswell.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to apply the `quantile` function on a survival object, where the function needs to be fed a numeric `vector`. The survival object contains this vector, but you need to extract it from it first. I use the leukemia data set from the survival package as an example;

```
library(survival)
data(leukemia)
surv.obj <- survfit(Surv(time = leukemia$time, event = leukemia$status) ~ 1)

names(surv.obj)
[1] "n"         "time"      "n.risk"    "n.event"   "n.censor"  "surv"   "type"     
[8] "std.err"   "upper"     "lower"     "conf.type" "conf.int"  "call"     

quantile(surv.obj$time)
  0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
5.00  13.75  27.50  33.75 161.00
```

Please note you can extract the quantiles for the lower and the upper boundary of the 95% CI as well by using the `quantile` function on `surv.obj$lower` and `surv.obj$upper`.

Comment: okay - it now works somehow, but I still don't get it: taking the example from here (http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/survival/html/quantile.survfit.html), `quantile(fit)` works. If I replace `fit` with `fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data=lung)` it doesn't work. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: There is a `survfit` method for the `quantile` function, so such objects should be handled properly without further manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I propose that nothing is wrong with the object, but rather you are attempting to misuse it. The median in the print(surv) statement uses information from the Surv(TAGE,EVENT) data, but that doesn't mean that quantile(surv) should necessarily work as you expect.